# Потеря возможности подключения к БД

Tags: база-данных

Делал приложение .NET WinForms, все работало в штатном режиме, но сегодня я получил ошибку

[image: Вылетает при попытке подключиться к БД]

Вылетает при любой попытке подключиться к БД. Как исправить?

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что Вы базу хранили в дропбоксе?

Comment: Да, именно так, в дропбоксе

Comment: и наверное, открываете ее с нескольких мест одновременно?

Comment: Нет, только с одной машины

Comment: Если было бы две машины - ошибка была очевидной. В любом случае хранить базу в дропбоксе - плохая идея. Но может быть диск начал сыпаться?

А что делать? а ничего. создавать базу по новой. Либо в дропбоксе посмотреть, там есть возможность откатить на пару ревизий назад.

Comment: @KoVadim можете, пожалуйста, объяснить, в чем была бы проблема при работе с разных машин (для меня просто это не очевидно)? Я правильно понял, что проблема в .mdf файле БД?

Comment: В большинстве известных мне случаях, база данных, когда работает с файлом базы, рассчитывает на то, что у нее монопольных доступ. И если файл меняется с нескольких мест, то может быть обычная гонка с порчей данных. Если возникает такая необходимость, нужно использовать сетевые базы данных.